# Spliting Arraylist in 2 and sorting it using different threads

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

So what I'm trying to do is have a main thread that will split an ArrayList in 2, then 2 other threads will be started and those threads will sort each half using bubble sort when they finish with sorting the main thread will combine the 2 halves into one sorted ArrayList.Can you please tell me where I am wrong

This is the main class:

```java
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Assignment3 implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t0 = new Thread(new Assignment3());
        t0.start();
    }

    public void run(){
        generateNumbers();
        Instant begin = Instant.now();

        List<Integer> numbers1 =numbers.subList(0,numbers.size()/2);
        List<Integer> numbers2 =numbers.subList((numbers.size()/2)+1,numbers.size() - 1);

        Thread1 t1 = new Thread1(numbers1);
        Thread1 t2 = new Thread1(numbers2);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> newNumbers1 =t1.getArray();
        ArrayList<Integer> newNumbers2 =t2.getArray();

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> numbersAll = new ArrayList<>();
        numbersAll.add(newNumbers1);
        numbersAll.add(newNumbers2);

        Instant end = Instant.now();

        Duration duration = Duration.between(begin, end);

        System.out.println(numbers);
        System.out.println(duration.getSeconds() + " Seconds");
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    public void generateNumbers(){
        for (int i = 0; i <25000 ; i++) {
            int number = (int)(Math.random()*25000)+1;
            numbers.add(number);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the thread class:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Thread1 extends Thread {

    public List<Integer> numbers;

    public Thread1(List<Integer> numbers) {
        this.numbers=numbers;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int n = numbers.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++){
                if (numbers.get(j) > numbers.get(j + 1)) {
                    // swap arr[j+1] and arr[i]
                    int temp = numbers.get(j);
                    numbers.set(j, j + 1);
                    numbers.set(j + 1, temp);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    public ArrayList<Integer> getArray(){
        return (ArrayList<Integer>) numbers;
    }

}
```

Also, this is the error I receive when I run it:
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList$SubList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    at Thread1.getArray(Thread1.java:27)
    at Assignment3.run(Assignment3.java:32)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Does this code work? If not, what happens? Do you get an error?

Comment: please edit your question and add this exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error above is the following line

`return (ArrayList<Integer>) numbers;`

You cannot cast `numbers` whose data type is List to a subclass i.e. ArrayList. 
You can instead replace it with

`return new ArrayList<Integer>(numbers);`

This will create a new ArrayList with elements in List.

While this will solve the error that you are getting it does not do what the original question asked for. 
After the 2 sub lists are sorted you will need to merge them using logic described [here](http://www.javatechblog.com/java/write-a-java-program-to-merge-two-sorted-arrays/) to get one sorted ArrayList.